# Radio button clicked to slide & show hidden div & pass a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to mimic the function on this url: https://www.healthcare.gov/find-premium-estimates/

I've provided a link and the code to what I have so far. I'm trying to create the same feature of the site like when you click an answer to the provided questions it then **slides you down** to the next question...

One issue I'm having with my jsfiddle example is if you click "No" on Question 2 it won't show the hidden div but, if you click "Yes" on the same question it then works... This also happens to question 3 if you click the "Don't Know".

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/0vc9ep17/34/

**Here is the HTML**

```
    <h1>Question 1</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer1">
    Answer 1
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer2">
    Answer 2
    <div class="answer1and2 hide">
    <h1>Question 2</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer3">
    Yes
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer4">
    No
    </div>
<div class="answer3 hide">
        <h1>Question 3</h1>
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="answer5">
            maybe
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="answer6">
            Don't know
            </div>
<div class="answer5 hide">
        <h1>Question 4</h1>
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="answer7">
            maybe
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="answer8">
            Don't know
            </div>
```

**Here is the Javascript**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
         if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "answer1") {
             jQuery(".answer1").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer1and2").show("slow");
         }
         if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "answer2") {
             jQuery(".answer2").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer1and2").show("slow");
         }
         if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "answer3") {
             jQuery(".answer3").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer4").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer1and2").show("slow");
         }
         if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "answer5") {
             jQuery(".answer1and2").show("slow");             
             jQuery(".answer3").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer4").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer5").show("slow");

         }

     });
 });
```

**Here is the CSS**

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: when I switch the `if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "answer4") ` to a answer4 it then shows the answers to question 3 & 4 at the same time..  [http://jsfiddle.net/0vc9ep17/45/](http://jsfiddle.net/0vc9ep17/45/)

Comment: Ha yes... just not so much javascript/jquery here is the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/0vc9ep17/50/ the questions work...

Comment: Good stuff... i tweaked it a little but works great overall & yes simplifying the code was much easier. do you know how to get it to slide down to the next question after one is answered? If you supply your answer in the answer section below i'll gladly vote yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With changing `<div class="answer1and2 hide">` to `<div class="answer1 answer2 hide">` code can be simplified and can cover all cases:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/0vc9ep17/51/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function()
    {
        jQuery("." + this.value).show("slow");
    });
});
```

If you want to scroll to shown question, you can use `$(window).scrollTop()` with shown question `.offset()` after `.show()` is done:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/0vc9ep17/63/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function()
    {
        var showingElement = jQuery("." + this.value);
        showingElement.show("slow", function()
        {
            jQuery(window).scrollTop(showingElement.offset().top); 
        });
    });
});
```

Note: to make scroll work correctly page height has to be more than window height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trigger for the events that arent firing, just like you have for the rest of them.

```
if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "answer4") {
         jQuery(".answer3").show("slow");
         jQuery(".answer4").show("slow");
         jQuery(".answer1and2").show("slow");
     }

if (jQuery(this).attr("value") == "answer6") {
             jQuery(".answer1and2").show("slow");             
             jQuery(".answer3").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer4").show("slow");
             jQuery(".answer5").show("slow");

         }`
```

Comment: the above code works great... here is an updated version http://jsfiddle.net/0vc9ep17/50/ I'm just now looking into sliding down to the next question once one question is answered. do you know off hand how to process this function?